# How can I prevent external hard disk from sleeping when connected to Airport Extreme?

Tags: hard-drive, airport, sleep-wake, external-disk

I have a 1TB external hard disk from Seagate connected to the USB port of my Airport Extreme and everytime I need to access it I have to wait some time until it leaves the sleep mode.

Is there a way to prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 5):

You can run [Keep Drive Spinning](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/31158/keep-drive-spinning) on a Mac that's connected to your drive over the network. It continuously accesses a hidden file to keep the drive awake.

You can also set it up yourself per [these instructions](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20011024160033481).

Answer (score 0):

If the computers on your network are Windows PCs, then you can map the shared network drive on one of your Windows boxes, then install [NoSleep HD 2.0](http://nosleephd.codeplex.com/).  Run the program, add that drive as the one to keep awake, and you are ready to go.

Comment: Mapping the drive might need some explanation on OS X.

Comment: Can you add some download information for NoSleep as well?

Comment: @patrix It's a Windows program. I suggested an edit. Since the OP didn't specify whether there are PCs or Macs on the Airport's network, there's value in this answer.